# Change connectionString dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, connection-string, vpn

I have a WinForm C# application that uses SQL server which needs to be accessed through VPN, the original connectionstring that we have on the server is:

```
connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDB;user id=myuser;password=mypass"
```

This connection string is at the app.config file

Everyone in the LAN can access the app and execute just fine, now when we connect through VPN, the connection to the SQL database doesn't work (obiously because the connectionstring needs to be different)

The IP we get when we connect using VPN may not always the same so my question is, can I dynamically change the connectionstring so that the user can input the Source when using VPN?

Thanks

Comment: You say the connection string on the server. Is this a windows app installed on each users desktop or a web app people connect to using their browser?

Comment: This is a windows app. Users execute this app from a shared folder sitting in the server where this app was deployed to.

Comment: You should really look in to getting an internal DNS server so you can just use a consistent host name instead of an IP.

Answer (score 1):

Use String.Format() to gernerate the connection string.

```
string datasource = DatasourceTb.Text;  // get value from user input.
string catalog = "MyDB";
string username = "myuser";
string password = "mypass";

string connectionString = 
    String.Format("Data Source={0}; Initial Catalog={1}; User Id={2}, Password={3};",                           

                        datasource,
                        catalog,
                        username,
                        password
                    );
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this is in the app.config section so I'd like to change it there

Comment: Use [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx), no need to use string manipulation.  It will make sure that the string is generated correctly.